# 7 inch tablet with resolution 480X800 layout issue

Tags: android, layout

I have

```
layout

layout-large

layout-xlarge
```

folders in my `res` folder.

But despite being a 7 inch tablet the layouts are picked from `layout` folder instead of layout-large.

and device runs on `android 4.0`

Am i missing something??
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check **Configuration examples** in [Supporting Multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: seems to work when i use  layout-sw480dp.
Will this layout will conflict with phones like 5 inches ???

Answer (score 2):

Check the correct device resolution and follow the charts offered by Android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**Configuration examples:**

To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

- 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
  hdpi, etc).
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

*in your case you need to create a  "layout-600dp" folder inside your "res" folder.*

Answer (score 0):

Because the DP of the device is 160dp/inch which falls under the category of mdpi devices